# Django DRF Serializer: ManyToMany on different PK

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a many to many field:

```
guests = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

How can a create a custom serializer field for this many to many field?

A requirement is the source must be from the username instead of the id field. 
Similar implementation for a single field is:

```
user_username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found:

```
guests = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), many=True, slug_field="username", required=False
    )
```